# Building raster (population density) dependend diagram in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, density, diagram

I'm using QGIS and trying to solve the following problem.

I got 2 layers:

1. population density raster
2. point layer with the information about number of people could be hosted/served etc in this points.

[image]

I want to show the area where such number of people (that could be
hosted/served) lives around this points (for instance, using circle diagrams).

I thought about creating multibuffer, then counting the number of people living
in each of them and manually trying to find the most appropriate size of it. However, I believe there is more rational option.

Could you please propose any solutions?